# Incline Plane - Coefficient of friction and kinetic friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

A block of mass 90 kg sits on a slope with an angle of inclination 12° above the horizontal. The coefficients of friction between the block and the slope are µk = 0.03 and µs = 0.2.

a.  What is the maximum frictional force that will allow the block to stay in place?

b.  At what angle of inclination will the block start to slide down the slope?

My Question:
I am not looking for these two questions to be answered, however, the question has caused me to doubt my understanding of static and kinetic friction re: incline planes.

When i calculated the  the angle at which the block would begin to slide, using the arc tangent of 0.2 i got an angle less than 12 degrees. However, the question is suggesting that the block is at rest with when the incline plane is at 12 degrees. What is my conceptual error in thinking?

My next question:

Wouldnt the minimum angle of the incline plane (tan inverse of 0.2) be needed in answering the first question? that is, having it placed in the formula for the static friction formula = 0.2 x 90kg x 9.81 x cos of (tan inverse of 0.2)? assuming that tan inverse of 0.2 was found already? Is there something wrong with the question or how am i thinking is conceptual flawed?

My Final Question:
Is it that the maximum frictional force that allow the block to stay in place is based on whatever angle the incline plane is set at? So, for example, if the incline plane is lowered to an angle of 5 degrees, the max friction force will be adjusted, even though the block would slide at 11.31 degrees? Is it that if lowered to 5 degrees, that the max friction force to overcome would be different?

In other words:
If a block is at rest on the incline plane  at an angle of 30 degrees, would the maximum frictional force that would allow the block to stay in place be calculated using 30 degrees, OR would we have to find the minimum angle of the incline plane needed for the block to slide before we can determine the maximum frictional force? That is, find that minimum angle and then substitute it in the formula for  fs(max) = UsMgcos (minimum angle needed for block to slide)?

Answer (score 1):

The question seems a mess.

> Is it that the maximum frictional force that allow the block to stay in place is based on whatever angle the incline plane is set at?

Using a coefficient of friction and a normal force, you can calculate a "maximum static friction force".  If the block is on a flat surface, friction will be zero.  As the surface is inclined or as an external force is applied, static friction can increase to some maximum value.  If stressed beyond this point, the static friction will not exceed this value and the object will start to slide.

But neither your question nor the one you included asks this.  Instead it asks what the maximum friction force is that will allow the block to stay in place.   That seems silly.  In this setup, there is only one frictional force (not a maximum) that will allow the block to remain still.  The question could (but doesn't) ask if this force is less than the maximum static force.

The rest of your confusion seems similar to that one.  There is no "maximum force" that will prevent it from moving.  Smaller forces will not hold it and it will slide down.  Larger forces (wouldn't really be friction at that point) would push it up the ramp.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding your first question:** I don't think there is any error in your thinking. The two forces acting on the body are the force of friction and gravity. Using the numbers you have provided ($m=90kg,\theta=12°,\mu_s=0.2$) we can set up the following equation:

$$mg \sin\theta-\mu_smg\cos\theta=F_{net} \\ \implies (9.81 \frac{m}{s^2})(90kg)\sin{12°-(0.2)(90kg)(9.81\frac{m}{s^2})\cos{12°}}=F_{net} \\ \iff F_{net}=10.84 N$$

There exists a non zero force in the downhill direction (I have omitted vectors here and chosen the x-axis to be parallel and the y-axis to be perpendicular to the plane) and therefore the mass will accelerate.

**Second question:** At what angle will the mass start sliding down the plane?

$$mg\sin{\theta}>\mu_s mg \cos{\theta} \\ \iff \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}=\tan{\theta>\mu_s} \\ \iff\theta>\arctan{\mu_S} \\ \implies\theta>11.31°$$

The mass will begin to slide once we have passed an angle of $11.31°$ and therefore, given the numbers you have provided and assuming there are no other forces acting on the it, the mass cannot be at rest at $12°$.

**Third question:**  I don't quite understand what you mean by "maximum frictional force" but  the force of (static) friction is a function of the angle and has a single value for every angle you set the plane at.